# Reading from MongoDB collection in mule

Tags: mongodb, mule, mule-studio

I am reading from MongoDB collection called attributes. I am getting the results back, but I want to restrict the results based on the query parameters.

Following is the code using which I am able to get all the records in the collections --

```
<flow name="readFromMongoDB" doc:name="insertInMongoDB">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        path="mdb-read-data-vm" doc:name="VM" />
    <json:json-to-object-transformer
        returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message=">>>>>>>> #[payload.name]" />
    <mongo:find-objects config-ref="Mongo_DB"
        collection="attributes" doc:name="Find Attribute">
    </mongo:find-objects>
    <mongo:mongo-collection-to-json />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

How can I mention query attributes to filter the results?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to refine my search using mongo:query-attribute within mongo:find-one-object-using-query-map

Here is the working code --

```
<flow name="readFromMongoDB" doc:name="readFromMongoDB">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        path="mdb-read-data-vm" doc:name="VM" />
    <json:json-to-object-transformer
        returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message=">>>>>>>> #[payload.name]" />
    <mongo:find-one-object-using-query-map
        config-ref="Mongo_DB" collection="#[collection]" doc:name="Mongo DB">
        <mongo:query-attributes>
            <mongo:query-attribute key="name">#[payload.name]</mongo:query-attribute>
        </mongo:query-attributes>
    </mongo:find-one-object-using-query-map>
    <mongo:dbobject-to-json doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message= "#[payload]" />
</flow>
```